# Java - Android studio

Tags: java, android

How do I get the output of `lt.getTest02()` *which is either a 1, a 2, or a 3* to display a 'word' on screen for each output. For example if the output is 1, display "Left" instead of the number '1'.....if output is 2 display "Centre" and if output is 3, display "Right". I tried a couple of methods but couldn't do it. I think I need a function for it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_back_to_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBackToMain);
    DatabaseHandler db = MainActivity.db;
    lt = MainActivity.linetest;
    //results


String textOutput = "Id: " + lt.getID() + " ,Patientid: " + lt.getPatientid() + " ,Timestamp: " + lt.getTimestamp()

                + "\n\n Test02: " + lt.getTest02()

                + "\n Test05: " + lt.getTest05()

                + "\n Test07: " + lt.getTest07()
                + "\n Test08: " + lt.getTest08()
                + "\n Test09: " + lt.getTest09()

                + "\n Test11: " + lt.getTest11()

                + "\n Test13: " + lt.getTest13()

                + "\n Test16: " + lt.getTest16()
                + "\n Test17: " + lt.getTest17()
                + "\n Test18: " + lt.getTest18()

                + "\n Test22: " + lt.getTest22()

                + "\n Test25: " + lt.getTest25()

                + "\n Test27: " + lt.getTest27()
                + "\n Test28: " + lt.getTest28()
                + "\n Test29: " + lt.getTest29()

                + "\n Test31: " + lt.getTest31()

                + "\n Test33: " + lt.getTest33()

                + "\n Test36: " + lt.getTest36()
                + "\n Test37: " + lt.getTest37()
                + "\n Test38: " + lt.getTest38()

        ;

        //displays on the screen
        textView.setText(textOutput);

OnClickButtonListener();
}
```

Comment: Well I don't know if I got it right but maybe you need something like a helper function to pass the return value of getTest02 for example to it and it will translate it to Left, Right or Centre

Comment: Any idea how that function can be written?? Coz i tried one already and couldn't do it.

Comment: @MsYvette thanks for the suggestion, but i'm not sure how to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment you can use the following helper function:

```
String helper(String index)
{
   if(index.equals("1")) return "Left";
   if(index.equals("2")) return "Right";
   if(index.equals("3")) return "Centre";
   return "";
}
```

and replace the following line:

```
+ "\n\n Test02: " + lt.getTest02()
```

with

```
+ "\n\n Test02: " + helper(lt.getTest02())
```

Comment: it says that i need a return statement in the helper function

if(index.equals("1")) return "Left";
   if(index.equals("2")) return "Right";
   if(index.equals("3")) return "Centre";

what shoud i return???

Comment: @EsidorPashaj check the edited code

Comment: helper(lt.getTest02())

 error saying cannot convert helper to int

Comment: where have you defined the helper function?

Comment: outside as a public string

Comment: define it inside of your class as a member function

Comment: not sure what you mean bro

Comment: Everything needs to be in a class to work so for example if you are working with default configuration of Android Studio you should have MainActivity class right?

Comment: put the helper function that I just described inside of that MainActivity class or any other class that you are going to use

Comment: @EsidorPashaj any progress?

Comment: im gona look at it now bro, left it at that yesterday

Comment: You'll want to modify `helper()` somewhat if `lt.getTest02()` returns an int ... `String helper(int index)` ... `if (index == 1) ...` etc.

Comment: It's ok guys I fixed it, thanks a mill tho :)

Comment: @EsidorPashaj Great! Please mark this answer as accepted so the question be closed